# Scikit-learn Decision Tree Classifier

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am trying to build a tree classifier with the scikit-learn package but I have problems getting the correct format for the classifier input..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#import dataset
data = pd.read_table('Data/Breast.csv')
data.head(10)
```

[image]

X=data[['clump_thickness','shape_uniformity','marginal_adhesion','epithelial_size','bare_nucleoli','bland_chromatin','normal_nucleoli','mitoses']]

```
X_train = X.values

Y = data[['class']]
Y_train = Y.values

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model 

model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```

But I get the following error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
last) <ipython-input-215-ffa49499a3bf> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(X_train,Y_train)

c:\users\tobias\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py
in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    788             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    789             check_input=check_input,
--> 790             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    791         return self
    792 

c:\users\tobias\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py
in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    114         random_state = check_random_state(self.random_state)
    115         if check_input:
--> 116             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
    117             y = check_array(y, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None)
    118             if issparse(X):

c:\users\tobias\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py
in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy,
force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    431                                       force_all_finite)
    432     else:
--> 433         array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    434 
    435         if ensure_2d:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'
```

What am I doing wrong?
I can see that X.values is of dType = Object...

Comment: have you tried converting your columns to [`numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)?

Comment: Almost all machine learning algorithms expect numerical matrices as an input. So you will need to convert your input data set to numeric values or to binarize it (depending on your data and your goals)...

Comment: Thanks, guys. And for the patience ;-).

What would be the appropriate method there - something like X.astype(int)?
Because I tried that and it didn't work. Can you just do int(X.values)?

Comment: Just FYI - after playing a bit more I found a solution for it
one can use the astype method directly on the panda frame:

`X = data[['clump_thickness','size_uniformity','shape_uniformity','marginal_adhesion','epithelial_size','bland_chromatin','normal_nucleoli','mitoses']].astype('float32')`

`Y = data[['class']].astype('int')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make sure you are passing integers, if your set contains strings or categorical values, or shows another issue, I'll edit this answer with the solution:

```
cols = ['clump_thickness','shape_uniformity','marginal_adhesion','epithelial_size','bare_nucleoli','bland_chromatin','normal_nucleoli','mitoses']
for col in cols:
     data[col] = data[col].astype('int') 
X.train = data[cols]
Y.train = data[['class]]

model = DecissionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
```